# isdigit() is not working?

Tags: c++, cin

When I enter a number and test it with isdigit, it always returns false, why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    int num;

    cin >> num;

    if(isdigit(num))
    cout << "Is a number";

    else
    cout << "That is not a number";

}
```

Sample input: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the intent of `isdigit` is to check a *character* for whether or not it's an ASCII digit. For instance:

```
if (isdigit('4')) {
    // yep
}
```

Or:

```
std::string str = "12345";
if (std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), isdigit)) {
    // ok this is safe
    int i = std::stoi(str);
}
```

It is basically checking if its input is between `'0'` and `'9'`. Which is to say, 48 and 57. It will return 0 for any other value.

Comment: Your second example has undefined behavior (and generally won't compile anyway).

Comment: @JamesKanze Compiles for me on both clang and gcc, what would the undefined behavior be?

Comment: @Barry: Well, you're missing a `)` and that `...` is not valid, for a start. The `isdigit` call is UB if any of `str`'s characters are <0. `str` has `char`s in it, but `isdigit` requires valid `unsigned char` representations. In reality, it's ludicrous to suggest that you'd run into problems with this.

Comment: Fixed the missing ). The "..." was intended to just be "fill in whatever here it's not important"

Comment: @Barry: Best to write `const std::string str = "98765";` then.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I regularly run into problems with it.  Just about any character with an accent will have a negative code representation.

Comment: @Barry What headers do you include?  If `<locale>` is included, either directly or indirectly (and it will often be included by `istream` or `ostream`), the call of `std::all_of` is ambiguous: in order to resolve `isdigit`, the compiler needs to know the type of `all_of`, and in order to resolve `all_of`, it needs to know `isdigit`.

Comment: I just want to point out that it is really sad that apparently we don't even have a safe call to check whether a character is a digit.

Comment: Just to be clear: you _cannot_ invoke the `isdigit` from `<cctype>` with a `char`; you must convert it to `unsigned char` first.  And C++ defines a large overloaded set of `isdigit`, some of which are templates.  So you can't pass a pointer to the function to a function template and expect resolution to work.

Comment: @Barry The problem is that whether a character is a digit or not may depend on the locale.  (At least in C++.  In C, `isdigit` is the only function in `<ctypes.h>` which isn't locale dependent.)

Comment: @James: That's not true. You _can_ invoke `isdigit` with a `char`, and you know you can. That there are restrictions and problems doesn't change that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can do it, but then you risk encountering undefined behavior.  If you like undefined behavior, fine.  Otherwise, you can't do it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Otherwise, you shouldn't do it.*